# Understanding how Wifi can be restricted to some computers

Tags: networking, security, wifi-configuration

I am in a company wifi network with a computer provided by this company. I can see that with this computer, the wifi can be connected without any credentials prompted to this network. However, if I used a personal computer or a mobile phone, I don't have access to this network.

My question is, what is installed on the corporate computer in order to connect to this network?
If it is a certificate, where can I find it, and if I copy this to another computer, can I achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such certificate to be copied.
You need to connect to the wifi network with the right credentials.

It is quite possible that your computer is known to the company by the
MAC address of its network adapter. In such a network,
no unregistered devices will be allowed without the administrator
allowing them in.

If you have a legitimate reason to connect other devices to the
company network, ask the network administrator.
Circumventing company security policies can be a reason
for dismissal, so beware.

The method you can use for your phone to have internet, would be to create
on your company computer an ad-hoc hotspot to which you may connect the phone,
if supported by its hardware.
Again, better find out first if that is allowed, as security policies
may not allow unsecured hotspots.

Comment: First, as @harrymc states,IT likjely has a white list, i.e. *authorized* computers. Second, the PC that connects likely has a network password stored - you would not be prompted. BTW, when an outside instructor brought his laptop in for a training session, at a site where I worked, security staff came the minute he tried to connect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I only want to know how a hacker can pass around this restriction for general culture. So my question is that if I modify a Mac address to be exactly the mac of the company computer, It should work? If the credentials are stored somewhere in the computer, how do I find it? The security type of the wifi is Microsoft Smart card or other certificate

Comment: Spoofing the MAC is possible, but Security will surely be alarmed when detecting two computers with the same MAC address. This is defined as hacking and even as internet theft. You may be bypassing some red lines for your company. Again: Talk with the admin, rather than trying a hack. This is my best advice.